# The sequence $(w_n(x))_n$ the sequence admits a finite limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuos increasing mapping. For all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we pose $w_n(x)=\frac{\phi^n(x)}{n}$ for all $n$.

we suppose that :

$1$. For all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

$$
|\phi^n(x)-\phi^n(y)|\leq k
$$
$2$. For all $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$
$$
\phi^n(0)+\phi^m(0)-1\leq \phi^{m+n}(0)\leq \phi^n(0)+\phi^m(0)+1
$$

**Problem:** Show that the sequence $(w_n(x))_n$ the sequence admits a finite limit independent of $x$.

***Hint:*** Show that the sequence $(w_n(0))_n$ converges and verify that its limit $l\in [\phi(0)-1,\phi(0)+1]$

I have already thought of applying Fekete's lemma to the sequence $(x_n)_n$ awith $x_n=\phi^n(0)+1$ such that its limit is $L =  \inf\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{x_n}{n}$. Can this be helping me a result?

An idea please.